# How Many Ostriches?

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

A great banquet was prepared for a Roman dictator and his entire family. 11 Kangaroos, 13 Monkeys, 23 Wallabies and 2 Bandicoots were served.

How many portions of Ostrich were served?

*EDIT: The answer is not 1 (apparently people think it is because Ostrich is singular, but no, that is not remotely correct).*

Comment: I think it has something to do with "Rome"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answer:

> 15

Explaination:

> O is the 15th letter in the Alphabet
>  as K is the 11th letter in the Alphabet (Kangaroos), and so on

Comment: Congratulations :)

Comment: Oh! I see it now.

Answer (score 5):

Answer:

> **1**

Explanation:

> How many portions of `Ostrich` were served?

**EDIT:**

> Here's an interesting text I found. 
>  *`They spent hundreds of thousands of denarii capturing, transporting, caring for, housing and training animals from all over the Empire.  They queued for hours outside their town's amphitheatres to watch the spectacle and marvel at strangely shaped camels, giraffes and ostriches.  They recognized the strength and importance of animals in war, transport, and agriculture.  They kept animals as ornaments, named and pampered them as pets, gave them a full burial, believed in an animal afterlife.`*

Comment: Sorry, but that isn't the correct answer lol although it's a good one. You get my +1. I'm pretty sure food is always measured as a singular noun, though :P

Comment: @NL628 in future questions maybe hedge the ambiguity that allows more than one logical question to be "right" (even if it is not the one you intended... we cannot yet read minds).

Comment: @Mindwin okay, sure I'll keep that in mind :)